# Solr - Get DocID of search result

Tags: solr

How can I get docID of result from solr?

What I am doing currently is,

I do search request in solr.

I get certain records (Say 10).

```
solrurl/start=0&rows=10
```

Now, again I do search request with below

```
solrurl/start=10&rows=10
```

So i get next 10 records.

Now new records are inserted in solr (Say 10 records). 
and Now If I do request again by 
    solrurl/start=20&rows=10

So I might get repeated records.

So if I have docID of than I can query by less than that docID.

So is it possible to get docID?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey), Solr does not need a unique id. What you want is the Lucence doc id. However, leaking internal Lucene implementation details is bad, especially since Lucene doc id's change when the index is mutated.

What you can do is, while entering data you can add an incrementing field which you could use to perform what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

[Use cases which require a unique key](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey)

> Add documents incrementally. You do not rebuild the index from scratch but want to add new documents periodically. You may add the same document twice and it will only be stored once.

This looks like your case. You may already have a field that can be used as unique identifier (in ex: `url` for a RSS article), otherwise take a look at the UUID field generated by Solr(it's declared diferently in the Solr 4.x)